# AJAX delete request + remove li by id

Tags: jquery, node.js, ajax

I want to delete a list item by clicking the 'x' button within it. When I click the 'x' button, it doesn't delete it. The AJAX response is "OK" but all my list items remain.

I've tried different options with .remove() in the success method; I've tried creating a separate delete function to call when the AJAX promise resolves; I've tried adding/removing key/value pairs in the AJAX request; I'm still new to AJAX requests and server-side operations, but documentation and videos haven't helped me with this problem.

```
const getAllChirps = () => {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/api/chirps/"
    })
        .then(chirps => {
            $('ul').empty();
            chirps.forEach(chirp => {
                $('ul').append(`<li id=${chirp.id} class="list-group-item"> 
            ${chirp.text} 
            <button onclick="deleteChirp()"> X </button>
            </li>`)
            })
        })
};
const deleteChirp = () => {
    let id = $('li').attr('id')
    alert('Delete button works');
    $.ajax({
        type: "DELETE",
        url: '/api/chirps/:' + id,
        success: function () {
            $('li').remove(id);
            getAllChirps();
        }
    }).then(res => console.log(res));
}
```

I want the list item to delete upon clicking the 'x' button. Instead, I get an 'OK' response in my console, and no list items delete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the button as argument to the deleteChirp function. Then find the parent li as the following demo.

```js
const getAllChirps = () => {
    $('ul').empty();
 for(var i=0; i<3; ++i)
  $('ul').append('<li id="A' + i + '" class="list-group-item">A' + i + ' Label<button onclick="deleteChirp(this)"> X </button></li>');
};

const deleteChirp = (ele) => {
    $(ele).closest("li").remove();
};

$(document).ready(function() {
    getAllChirps();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul><li>Test</li></ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem is that `deleteChirp` don't know what `li` it should refer to in `let id = $('li').attr('id')`

Have you tried adding the id to the click function?

```
onclick="deleteChirp('+chirp.id+')"
```

Then you can get it from in the function like this:

```
const deleteChirp = (liId) => {
```

Full code:

```
const getAllChirps = () => {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/api/chirps/"
    })
        .then(chirps => {
            $('ul').empty();
            chirps.forEach(chirp => {
                $('ul').append(`<li id=${chirp.id} class="list-group-item"> 
            ${chirp.text} 
            <button onclick="deleteChirp('+chirp.id+')"> X </button>
            </li>`)
            })
        })
};
const deleteChirp = (liId) => {
    let id = liId
    alert('Delete button works');
    $.ajax({
        type: "DELETE",
        url: '/api/chirps/:' + id,
        success: function () {
            $('li#'+id).remove();
            getAllChirps();
        }
    }).then(res => console.log(res));
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't resolve the issue; I get the same result (li doesn't delete).

Comment: After the html is generated try inspect the button and see if it has an id inside `deleteChirp()` also it should be `$('li#' + id).remove();`